# How to write unit testing for socket service

Tags: angular, socket.io, karma-jasmine

```
 this.proctoringSocket.on('ia-ie', (args: any) => {
        $(document).trigger('ia-ie', args || {});
      });
```

writing unit testing Angular jasmine karma for socket service socket.io-client

```
 this.proctoringSocket.on('ia-ie', (args: any) => {
         $(document).trigger('ia-ie', args || {}); 
      });
```

Unable get response from callback function in socket service

Comment: https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/unit-testing-socket-io-with-jasmine/